# input function : python

Tags: python, numbers

```
counttonum = 1
countnum = input("[•] Provide A Number :")
 while counttonum < countnum:
   print("[", counttonum, "] : Number = ", counttonum)
   counttonum +=1
```

I was trying to make a counting tool that counts up to the provided number from the “input()” function.

For example:
providedNumberFromInput = 5
output = 1
2
3
4
5

And it’ll stop if the provided number is reached. Please help me.

Comment: `input()` returns a string

Comment: Although experienced programmers can find your problems, it is better to clearly write your doubts or errors in your problem. Here, `input` always returns a string. You need to convert it to a number by yourself. If necessary, you also need to do some checks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close to solution. Problem is that input() returns value as string so you will need to convert it. And also if you want to include entered number use `<=` instead of `<`

`while counttonum <= int(countnum):`